# How can I store the value of GetSec() in a variable at a specific time without the variable value changing with GetSec()?

Tags: c, function, timer

I'm trying to implement a function that ensures that a minimum time on before turning off and a minimum time off before turning on.

I tried to do this, but I saw that it doesn't work xd

```
LEDOn();//I turn on the LED
timeLEDOn = GetSec(); // I took the time when the LED turned on.GetSec() is a function that returns the time in seconds since the microcontroller was turned on.
 if (GetSec() - timeLEDOn >= MIN_TIME_ON) // I check if the current time minus the time the LED was turned on is greater than the minimum on time.
{LEDOff();}
```

But when doing this I realized that because the value of GetSec() is always changing, timeLEDOn also changes, so the subtraction would always be 0.

How can I store the value of GetSec() in a variable, at a given time without the value of the variable changing with GetSec()?
Hope you can guide me. :)

Comment: ...what **is** `GetSec`, exactly? What does it return? Is it expected to block?

Comment: "timeLEDOn also changes" No, not unless you change it. It is just a variable stored in memory. What you may have to worry about is any concurrency issue with GetSec reading the time vs. whatever is updating the time (Did you write it? This would be internal to GetSec and is platform dependent.) Also you need proper handling when the rollover back to 0 of what GetSec returns occurs during your time period.

Comment: Do you realize that you have to continue poll the time until enough time has passed, not just check it once? Doing this is usually factored into your design at a higher level than what you are showing us. How depends on what else the software needs to do at the same time. In the super simple case where the software has absolutely no other responsibilities, you could turn your if statement into a loop. In most situations there is other stuff to worry about.